# How to append data to text file in python 2.7.11?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, text, file-io

Could any one show me how i can add hyperlinks to new line in text file? If there is already data in first line of text file i want the data get inserted in the next empty line. I am writing multiple hyperlinks to text file(append). Thanks in advance.

```
    print "<a href=\"http://somewebsite.com/test.php?Id="+str(val)+"&m3u8="+lyrics+"&title=test\">"+str(i)+ "</a> <br />";
```

Comment: `my_file = open('file.txt', 'a+'); my_file.write(my_string);` ? (this will overwrite, but have you tried using file/write yet?)

Comment: Thanks for replyes. I tried it but it writes all the my_string in one line after each other . Is there a way to write each my_string in sperate line when multiple time it is called ?

Comment: You could have each string stored in a list (etc.) and then iterate over the list in a `for` loop. At the end of each string you write, make sure a newline is appended (i.e. `\n`.)

Comment: Thanks that fixed the problem :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you append to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the python [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

You can use the `with open` statement to open the file.

```
with open(filename, 'a') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can collect the strings you want to write to the file in a list (etc.) and then use python's built-in file operations, namely `open(<file>)` and `<file>.write(<string>)`, as such:

```
strings = ['hello', 'world', 'today']

# Open the file for (a)ppending, (+) creating it if it didn't exist
f = open('file.txt', 'a+')

for s in strings:
    f.write(s + "\n")
```

See also: [How do you append to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file-in-python)